# Need to pull username of current logged in user to input in a field

Tags: javascript, html, css, authentication, sharepoint

We have a small form that users can fill out to chat with a member of the help desk. It asks their name, email, phone number, and what their question is. If accessed from the Sharepoint, the Name field is pre-filled and unable to be changed. I had to remove that portion when I pulled the code for the self-help page, as several bits of the javascript call function were tied with sharepoint editing permissions.

What I'm wondering is if there is some way to pull the name or username of the currently logged in user to fill in that field instead? Eventually I plan on adding SSO integration, but I'm learning as I go along so that may be awhile off yet. I have included a portion of the original link below, where `'+str+'` was pulling the username from sharepoint, and removing it was leaving the field free for input.

```
http://SERVERNAME?cname='+str+'&cemail=&cphone=&activeimage=
```

I may not have been clear, this project lives outside of SharePoint, so any code reliant on it would not work here.

Answer (score 0):

If the user's username is in the query string, Sharepoint designer Rob Howard has [provided the Javascript he uses](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2007/06/13/using-javascript-to-manipulate-a-list-form-field/) to pull values into the form field. So try to replace `+str+` in the URL with the username, if that's not too insecure.